# How does Facebook manage sessions?

Tags: facebook

I have been observing how Facebook manages browser cookies and I noticed that they change the session cookies almost every second by Ajax polling. I would like to know how does Facebook manage user sessions and how do they do it for users on *remember me* setting. Are *remember me* sessions indefinite? If not, for how long are they active?